# How to set OnClickListener in ImageView which is inside a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, row, listener

I have a ListView with some items in each row. One of these items is a ImageView clickable. I created a separate Adapter class to create the ListView and fill it with all items.

In my Activity, I set this Adapter, as below:

```
//myScenesArray is the array of items I want to fill in the Adapter
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sceneslistview);
ListViewScenesAdapter customListAdapter = new ListViewScenesAdapter(this.getBaseContext(), R.layout.scenesrow, myScenesArray);
listView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
```

I can create Listener to each row, as below:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
    //here I put what I want to do when Listener is activated
});
```

**But how can I create a Listener to an item inside the row?**

I only access the items of my row inside the Adapter... Look the code below, the method getView() of my Adapter, when I fill all the elements:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i("ADAPTER DE CENAS","ENTROU NO getView()!!!");
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    ImageView left = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.left);
    left.setImageBitmap( (data.get(position)).getVisualImage() );
    TextView middle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text);
    middle.setText( (data.get(position)).getVisualName() );
    View right = row.findViewById(R.id.right);
    right.setTag(position);
    return row;
}
```

Can I access the elements of each row in my Activity?

I want to set a Listener to the View called right (R.id.right), in each row. I appreciate any help.

Updated

I already have the context as a variable of my Adapter class. I will post the beginning of the Adapter class:

```
public class ListViewScenesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Scene> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Scene> data = new ArrayList<Scene>();

public ListViewScenesAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Scene> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    Log.i("ADAPTER DE CENAS","ENTROU NO CONSTRUTOR!!!");
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}
```

The Adapter class has the constructor above, the getView method already mentioned and the variables: context, layoutResourceId and data.

But I dont know how to do a Listener inside the Adapter class. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Both ayorhan and Embattled Swag answered correctly, I think the same time, only different in edited. Both work fine, but when I access the variable POSITION (to know the current position of the list I am clicking), it shows an error. How can I get the position of this item inside the listener?

Comment: If one of you both help me to discover, I will mark as the final correct answer. And thanks me for all help!!!

Comment: @Embattled Swag see this

Comment: what's the error you're getting? in the ListView, only the visible items are created and as you scroll, you don't inflate new layouts, you reuse the ones from the top that becomes invisible. You need to take this into account, if you'd like to access to the children of list view.

Comment: This error: Cannot refer to a non-final variable position inside an inner class defined in a different method.

Comment: @ayorhan Because position is an argument of getView() method.

Comment: just make it final, it'll work. and it's the correct way to use the variable, position. public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

Comment: Yes! I dont know the difference, but it really worked! Thanks me! you help me a lot! :)

Comment: But why is it the correct way? What is the difference?

Comment: Marked as the correct answer.

Comment: you're welcome :) the reason is, final means you can't re-assign a value to it, and to be able to use it in the onClick method of the listener, it shouldn't be changed and making it final makes sure that it won't.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45139/discussion-between-sarah-sakamoto-and-ayorhan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the listener to the `ImageView` in the `getView` method of your adapter. If you need to access any variable from your activity, you can simply pass them as parameters to your adapter constructor.

```
// This will set separate listeners to all of the right views.
right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // Do whatever you want here, you can use the position variable to handle current view specifically  
          data.get(position); // this is the data you have in this listView item       
      }
);
```

Comment: Can I set a Listener inside the Adapter?!

Comment: I updated my answer! Of course you can do. It does assign listeners to all of the items separately and position variable shows the current item.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your getView()

```
holder.imgIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ImageClick"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

        }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it right in `getView`.

If you need access to any information from the context, you can simply pass the `Context` in the constructor of the `Adapter` and get any info from there.

You can do it like:

```
right.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        Toast.makeText(context,"You clicked image " + position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have the context as a variable of the Adapter class. But I dont know how to do a Listener inside the Adapter. And does it work? I thought I could only make listeners inside the Activity or Fragment classes.

Comment: @SarahSakamoto I put an example in my answer. It should work fine.